# PSCP - Copy extensionless files from Windows to Linux-based OS

Tags: linux, windows, raspberry-pi, pscp

So I have been struggling to copy a file without an extension from Windows to a Raspberry Pi using PSCP provided by PuTTY. However, Windows requires an extension in the command (just a dot after the filename if none, which is the problem) and the Raspberry Pi will keep the dot in the filename. The reason I want to do this is because the file is an executable file I compiled on Windows. If I try to execute the file with the dot at the end it just outputs `Permission denied`. If I try the same with sudo it outputs `command not found`.
Some commands that I have tried:

```
pscp "C:\example\bin\example" pi@192.168.100.44:/usr/local/exampledir/
```

To my knowledge the above tries to send a folder named example through pscp which cannot be found. This would work on the Raspberry Pi end, but not on the Windows end.
The following one will send the file successfully but it leaves the dot at the end of the file on the Raspberry Pi. Notice the dot I added.

```
pscp "C:\example\bin\example." pi@192.168.100.44:/usr/local/exampledir/
```

The last thing I tried was to specify the filename that it would have on the Raspberry Pi end, again without success:

```
pscp "C:\example\bin\example." pi@192.168.100.44:/usr/local/exampledir/example
```

Thanks in advance!